# Stochastic gradient descent overflow error

Tags: python, optimization, machine-learning, computer-vision, neural-network

I implemented a mini batches stochastic gradient descent using python. The model here is SVM and softmax model. Here is the content of the optimizer:

```
loss, grad = loss(X_batch, y_batch, reg)
W -= learning_rate * grad
```

For some value of learning rate and regularization parameter, it works perfectly (it passes the gradient checking)

```
iteration 0 / 1500: loss 794.507350
iteration 100 / 1500: loss 29.568095
iteration 200 / 1500: loss 33.458495
iteration 300 / 1500: loss 18.304720
iteration 400 / 1500: loss 35.882488
iteration 500 / 1500: loss 21.490048
iteration 600 / 1500: loss 25.785373
iteration 700 / 1500: loss 22.813580
iteration 800 / 1500: loss 25.500039
iteration 900 / 1500: loss 24.819413
iteration 1000 / 1500: loss 15.608862
iteration 1100 / 1500: loss 22.731321
iteration 1200 / 1500: loss 26.022119
iteration 1300 / 1500: loss 20.588262
iteration 1400 / 1500: loss 23.737331
That took 16.041453s
```

However if I set a smaller learning rate/ larger regularization coeff, it goes to infinity easily.

```
iteration 0 / 1500: loss 802.769833
iteration 100 / 1500: loss 402010684912951517714160259531836227584.000000
iteration 200 / 1500: loss 66449146544223774690669308194838812744571030707457444354059618517426110464.000000
iteration 300 / 1500: loss 10983511737783225854597341204492232891393029195591698817237023075664722703077635057235569132488177530617987072.000000
iteration 400 / 1500: loss 1815486524175816065194879215518721785434014355721054994732056447366189069461661764367553711338715612291351514721201526014636467439510904624906240.000000
iteration 500 / 1500: loss 300085382357794494911213874061735327359248402577239262036553372454999306473258608281908717386082743259637422311405675655718344736088310092775477346890221645805861568848900053270528.000000
iteration 600 / 1500: loss 49601710343569850904008263569832035647932127145181615050392357841588796262557064950546589884591619227102632956834873550818712373623620724060742653598312083408633957433671568944564242236660656086159625258558214373376.000000
iteration 700 / 1500: loss 8198765463603785409686242099308047610060840590000243139990894837982240050293849610436998843183936014375298887308342856825809426287886468401376324562159947921470840145036302068723165705243202367572424942890685882166121392632827736787223859487240617984.000000
iteration 800 / 1500: loss 1355190267867357287705764546778522627576836845623844275975557230456460933397253991581163373195663111196172764626006669963061476094064927997512717916334132304539774742926463546477992463418428065245444868204942968447224877690702413263146519713454691766809999132152180155000809790950604800.000000
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars
```

Is this a bug in my code, or a general optimization problem? How can I avoid this problem?

Comment: Can you include the code for the loss and grad functions? Otherwise I can't see what's going on in your code. That said, maybe you could try replacing loss with log loss?

Comment: Also, please add the values at which the algorithm fails to converge.  Step sizes and starting points are critical for optimization algorithms.

Comment: If you only reduce learning rate, it shouldn't explode like this.